# Slicing python list into new python lists

Tags: python, list, slice

I tried to do a slice a list into three new lists but seems my method is problematic. Can you guys help me to see how I should do it? Thank you！

```
quiz = [[91, 94, 38, 48, 70, 85, 94, 59], [78, 96, 90, 55, 77, 82, 94, 60], [99, 94, 82, 77, 75, 89, 94, 93], [49, 92, 75, 48, 80, 95, 99, 98]]
midterm = []
final = []
```

I tried to make quiz to have the first five number of the list, midterm then have the next two, and final has the last number of the list:

```
quiz = [[91, 94, 38, 48, 70,], [78, 96, 90, 55, 77], [99, 94, 82, 77, 75,], [49, 92, 75, 48, 80]]
midterm = [[85, 94,],[82, 94,], [89, 94,], [95, 99,]]
final = [[59], [60], [93], [98]]
```

And here is my code:

```
quiz = [[91, 94, 38, 48, 70, 85, 94, 59], [78, 96, 90, 55, 77, 82, 94, 60], [99, 94, 82, 77, 75, 89, 94, 93], [49, 92, 75, 48, 80, 95, 99, 98]]
midterm = quiz[5:2]
final = midterm[5:1]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are running into?

Answer (score 1):

```
midterm = [i[5:7] for i in quiz]
final = [i[7:] for i in quiz]
quiz = [i[:5] for i in quiz]
```

How this works:

[ ] is a condensed version of a for loop. 
For example, the above code is the same as the following:

```
for i in quiz:
    midterm.append(i[5:7])
for i in quiz:
    final.append(i[7:])

tmp = []
for i in quiz:
    tmp.append(i[:5])
quiz = tmp
```

Which pretty much iterates through all of the elements in quiz and takes the two and the one and the five for the separate arrays. What you were doing wrong is that you did not treat quiz as a two dimensional array, but as a one dimensional array.

Your current code takes the second through fifth elements of the array quiz for midterm, which happen to be the second through fifth arrays of integers, not the second through fifth integers in each array in quiz.

Answer (score 0):

here you go: using `list comprehension`

```
>>> quiz = [[91, 94, 38, 48, 70, 85, 94, 59], [78, 96, 90, 55, 77, 82, 94, 60], [99, 94,  82, 77, 75, 89, 94, 93], [49, 92, 75, 48, 80, 95, 99, 98]]
>>> new_quiz = [ x[:5] for x in quiz ]
>>> mid_term = [ x[5:7] for x in quiz ]
>>> final = [ x[-1:] for x in quiz ]
>>> new_quiz
[[91, 94, 38, 48, 70], [78, 96, 90, 55, 77], [99, 94, 82, 77, 75], [49, 92, 75, 48, 80]]
>>> mid_term
[[85, 94], [82, 94], [89, 94], [95, 99]]
>>> final
[[59], [60], [93], [98]]
```